# Importing a bunch of users from csv spreadsheet file into Drupal 8

Tags: 8, users, migrations, importing-exporting

I have a large csv spreadhseet list of users with name, email, phone and username. The passwords can be the same for all as they will be blocked anyway.

I know there is an old tutorial of importing users via the migrate api in drupal 8 from here: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/migrating-users-drupal-7-to-drupal-8

But that article is from 2014. Is there a new upto date way of doing this without the need to create a custom module? Is there a simple gui interface to get this imported? Or is there no choice but to make that custom migrate module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Migrate Source CSV](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_source_csv)

I know that it uses drush and can import nodes through mapping it in a twig file and I'm pretty sure that it supports users too.

Full steps located [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/using-the-migrate-source-csv-plugin).

Comment: thank you, but when i see drush status: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() CSV.php:123  .what can i do for this?