# Import users from a CSV file

Tags: 8, importing-exporting

How can I import users fom a CSV file in Drupal 8?

I’ve found this module but it is not updated for Drupal 8:

https://www.drupal.org/project/user_import

I think that I can make an import directly with a MySQL script but is it possible with Drupal (I know I can insert datas directly into database but I don't know if Drupal system will allow that method)?

I’ve found this question but it is not exactly what i need :
[Importing a bunch of users from csv spreadsheet file into Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222223/importing-a-bunch-of-users-from-csv-spreadsheet-file-into-drupal-8)

I import data from a csv file and it is not a migration from a drupal site.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the source isn't a Drupal site. Migrate is designed to work with various datasources, which has great support for CSV files of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it with Migrate you need to setup Migrate Plus, Migrate Tools and Migrate Source CSV together, there is lot of examples in the web already:

http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-migrate-users-from-a-csv-file-drupal-8

https://agencychief.com/blog/drupal-8-csv-migration

https://www.mtech-llc.com/blog/lucas-hedding/migrating-using-csv

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what i need. Your 3 links are really interesting. I’ve used the 1st one and it works. The 2nd is based on a custom module and i will  try it. The 3rd is written by the maintainer of the D8 Migrate Source CSV contrib module so it s also an excellent article.

Comment: So i can import a list of users. Now, i have to import datas in a custom module that contains datas related to the user. I see it is possible but didn’t try it yet : https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/process-plugin-migration_lookup-formerly-migration

Answer (score 2):

> I think that I can make an import directly with a MySQL script but is
>   it possible with Drupal (I know I can insert datas directly into
>   database but U don't know if Drupal system will allow that method)?

Instead of MySQL this would be a Drupal method to insert users by using the Entity API:

```
$user = User::create([
  'name' => 'foobar',
  'mail' => 'foobar@example.com',
  'status' => TRUE,
]);
$user->save();
```

So if you don't want to use Migrate there are other ways for such a simple import task. You can use a php library of your choice to fetch the data and then add the user entities one by one. I answered a similar question for importing nodes at a time when Migrate was still in alpha: [Is there a way to migrate only nodes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185398/is-there-a-way-to-migrate-only-nodes/185435#185435)

Answer (score 0):

Here I found the solution for it. Please follow this link https://github.com/steveoliver/user_import and install the extended module.
You can import the user data file through this path (path: '/admin/people/import').

Comment: Interesting. I’ll try it. But I see that it only handles fname,lname,email. In @drupalranger answer, there are links that explain how to import custom datas (like job, image, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

[User CSV Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_csv_import) is the module you want.

Migrate is a powerful and robust platform for integrating any arbitrary data source, but User CSV Import is tailor made for uploading CSVs of user data.

https://www.drupal.org/project/user_csv_import

There are other modules, like Bulk User Registration, which are less featureful. For example Bulk User Registration doesn't support any fields - you must manually write code to handle fields.